# Exploring philosophy behind "Catch-22" novel: individual in war

Tags: philosophy-of-war, individualism, libertarianism, awareness

I am looking for the name and possibly deeper development of the [system of ethics / morality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics) exemplified by the attitude of Yossarian, the main protagonist of [Catch-22 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22) by Joseph Heller. Yossarian's primary concern is his own safety:

> Havermeyer was a lead bombardier who never missed. Yossarian was a lead bombardier who had been demoted because he no longer gave a damn whether he missed or not. He had decided to live forever or die in the attempt, and his only mission each time he went up was to come down alive.

- Yossarian cannot be really called a *coward*, since he is not believing in the war in which he is fighting and the necessity of his sacrifice (at least not in the way these are viewed by his superior officers, such as Colonel Cathcart).
- Neither is he a *conscientious objector* or a *pacifist*, since he is not really objecting the war, but only the risks that it poses to him. Unlike his friend Dunbar, Yossarian is not willing to risk a court-martial (indeed, this would compromise his personal safety)
- Yossarian also cannot be called a [*free rider*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-rider_problem), as he is not aiming to benefit from the war being fought by others.

Perhaps, his attitude is some form of [individualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualism) or [liberatrianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarianism), since his beliefs are ultimately grounded in the dangers the war poses personally to him, and he considers anyone oblivious to these dangers as crazy.

Quote about personal dangers:

> “They're trying to kill me," Yossarian told him calmly.
> "No one's trying to kill you," Clevinger cried.
> "Then why are they shooting at me?" Yossarian asked.
> "They're shooting at everyone," Clevinger answered. "They're trying to kill everyone."
> "And what difference does that make?”

About craziness (the attitude is apparently shared by the author - at least it is taken as the basis of the discussion):

> There was only one catch and that was Catch-22, which specified that a concern for one’s own safety in the face of dangers that were real and immediate was the process of a rational mind. Orr was crazy and could be grounded. All he had to do was ask; and as soon as he did, he would no longer be crazy and would have to fly more missions. Orr would be crazy to fly more missions and sane if he didn’t, but if he was sane, he had to fly them. If he flew them, he was crazy and didn’t have to; but if he didn’t want to, he was sane and had to. Yossarian was moved very deeply by the absolute simplicity of this clause of Catch-22 and let out a respectful whistle.

[In my answer in another thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/94634/61899) I have called this attitude *Yossarianism*. I am interested in exploring it deeper, particularly in the context of an individual vis-à-vis war.

**Remark:** Note that the question is not about the logical paradox, also known as Catch-22, and popularized by the novel (as discussed, e.g., in [this thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)).)

Comment: It is an instance of (state/buraucracy) [Absurdism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism), as has been expressed in [Kafka's writings (eg the Trial)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial)

Comment: @NikosM. *absurdism* certainly makes a part of the narrative, but this does not summarize it. Any individual in war (e.g., Ukrainians and Russians) may pose themselves a question of whether they want to die for the goals proclaimed by their governments, social ideals, etc.

Comment: War, in a sense, is the corollary of (state) absurdism. Compare "War is Peace" in [1984 novel by George Orwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)

Comment: @NikosM. I personally agree with that, but this is not what the majority of the mankind thinks... or at least not the majority of western public.

Comment: ["*..the novel was "positioned teasingly ... between literature and literature's opposites – between Shakespeare and Rabelais and Dickens and Dostoevsky and Gogol and Céline and the Absurdists and of course Kafka on the one hand ..*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22#Literary_allusions)

Comment: @NikosM. still, the question is not about the world described in the novel and how closely it resembles reality, but about the individual attitude vis-à-vis the war.

Comment: Sure I do not intend to bypass your question, simply providing pointers. Well as Camus said, the correct response to the Absurd, is to defy it, and go on. To live it through, defiant. Everything other response being a kind of compromise and a defeat.

Comment: "*I'm not afraid of war, I just don't want to be there when it happens.*"

Comment: Did you notice that "Catch 22" revealed a thought previously unthunk, unless that be by Orwell's "double-think"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I do clearly separate these things. Your attack is unwarranted and I flagged it as unfriendly/hostile.

Comment: @RogerVadim Sorry no-one told me your skin was so thin.

Despite that, if you think I made any "attack", you will of course be able to cite the details…

Please either cite the details, or fess up to your mistake.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin it seems that you (or the moderators) have deleted the comments that I was referring to. So you are not acting in good faith here.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm sorry I no memory of that, or knowledge of what Moderators did…

I know not where any idea of "attack" came from.

When you're still looking for the name and possibly deeper development of the system of ethics / morality exemplified by Yossarian in Catch-22, why is that?

Are you saying Yossarian's system of ethics or morality doesn't show up in your own research or what, please?

Answer (score 5):

It is worth contrasting what people say, with what they do. It's actually difficult to get people to shoot to kill, with [estimates between 25% & 75% of soldiers only willing to do this](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1493456.Acts_of_War). In human history war was generally a last resort, with armies being drawn up and then often negotiations done if things were obviously going to go one way - we aren't so good at remembering those cases. It was much easier to find one champion to fight to death, than pursuade an entire army to do so. The ideal in war is to willingly die for your comrades, but when people volitionally do that or seriously risk that, they get special medals - and not many of them get awarded. You can order someone to do something dangerous, but a system of punishment can't force someone into certain death - because what greater punishment could there be to enforce that? It has to be chosen.

It's worth considering the idea that society is created through an implicit social contract. We gain collective benefits, and commit to certain costs, and we get society. The contentions between powers and cultures, have very often come down to who will fight to preserve the system they have, and how fiercely. The fact you can't order people to die on pain of death, has meant people who have shown willingness to take on that risk have often been accorded special sway, from membership of the demos in Ancient Athens requiring military service, to votes for women in the UK being driven by war service far more than suffragettes actions (who admitted with their pre WW1 bombing campaign that their tactics weren't working).

I would look to Game Theory, and the Evolutionary Theory of Multi Level Selection to make sense of this. If a group or class within a society can order others to die, but themselves are insulated from the processes of selection, that risks the creation of a free-rider problem, that can destabilise the system, or create fractures that fragment the society in extremis, like war. Russia is a pretty good example: WW2 where is was a shared existential threat, versus Ukraine where it seems to be about Putin's vanity - shared priorities, versus defence of an elite's priorities. Discussed in more detail here:
[Is the tyrannicide perpetrated by William Tell morally legitimate?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78788/is-the-tyrannicide-perpetrated-by-william-tell-morally-legitimate/78853#78853)

I'd look to the history of sagas epics and religions, to understand the emergence of ideas that people felt were worth dying for, discussed here:
[What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life from an agnostic or atheist view?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017)

Yossarian is fundamentally an example of an agent with rational self-interest, as assumed in economic theories until very recent times, as summarised in the idea of '[homo economicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_economicus)'. A freely-associating rational self-interested agent, simply cannot be pursuaded that they should die, unless perhaps they are reacting to kin-selection of protecting family. As I see it that is what Catch 22 draws out: *The contradiction between the mythos associated with war and heroism, and the pervasive idea that we are rational individuals* (which is not unchallenged, see the homo economics article).

WW1 poetry drew out a similar tension or contradiction, between the mythos of war and supposed rewards of symbolic immortality:

> "As the stars that shall be bright when we are dust, Moving in marches
> upon the heavenly plain, As the stars that are starry in the time of
> our darkness, To the end, to the end, they remain." -closing verse of
> RL Binyon's 'For The Fallen'

And the challenge of the lived experience to find what could justify it's necessity:

> "If you could hear, at every jolt, the blood Come gargling from the
> froth-corrupted lungs, Obscene as cancer, bitter as the cud Of vile,
> incurable sores on innocent tongues,— My friend, you would not tell
> with such high zest To children ardent for some desperate glory, The
> old Lie: *Dulce et decorum est Pro patria mori.*" *-closing lines of
> Wilfred Owen's 'Dulce et Decorum Est'*

I wouldn't call Yossarianism a fully developed philosophy. But instead an investigation of War, a questioning of whether in truth it can be rational to accept an order to die, and to die for the sake of an order.

I would argue based on a social contract theory of society, game theory, and Multi Level Selection, that ordering people to die for aims which don't serve them or their descendents, is not rational to demand people participate in.

But, what serves us and our descendents, is the product of endless tensions and negotiation, to discover. And is in the realm of mythos and trans-personal meaning, not of rationality. Deciding what we would die for, involves knowing what is required to make life worth living, which is not the result of analysis, but is a felt response to our our entire situation.

Comment: Great analysis! I think the real contradiction when force is used, is that there is no rational way to stop it. You are forced to reply with force, which is irrational. "*War doesn't decide who is right, only who is left.*" (Maybe we should all go left?)

Comment: +1 Thank you. I disagree though that war has been treated as *last resort* throughout human history - a champion fighting to death or fighting till the enemy run was true in ancient Athens, but finished with Alexander the Great (whose major strategic innovation was pursuing the enemy and killing as many as possible.) Death punishment is a good way to drive people into a battle - Trotsky openly stated that this was the only way he could motivate troops in the civil war, and Stalin later used the infamous *barrier troops* on the massive scale - no one really wanted to die for the Communists.

Comment: @RogerVadim: I said, carefully, 'war was generally a last resort'. I'd in mind the larger scope of human history. I'll accept psychotechnologies involved have got so good at tolerating lose-lose outcomes, we have Mutually Assured Destruction. My core contention, is that following Marshall's research & Holmes' review of it, it's hard to get people to murder each other without a lot of brutalising & dehumanisation first. In Ireland they had a tradition of champions to avoid battles at fords. + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_of_the_Thirty (1351AD). Coerced forces still have a slim choice

Comment: @ScottRowe: It wasn't the Allies 
who saw that dark tide turned. 
But Russians, and Germans, 
thirty millions of them
Who beat down that fire 
from when the Reichstag burned. 
It was in Stalingrad, 
where their own dead buried them. 

It was not guns or hope, 
but deaths that won. 
Because all tyrants can make, 
is ruins and dead men. 
The innocents of that time 
must not be forgotten - 
And that tyrants should die, 
before dead men bury them.

Comment: You would think that people would learn that force is ultimately self-defeating, but it is not chosen by reasoning, at least, not correct reasoning.

Comment: @ScottRowe: 'What are the arguments for revenge and retribution?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94137/what-are-the-arguments-for-revenge-and-retribution/94143#94143 'If we had the ability to make humanity less war-like, should we?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90783/if-we-had-the-ability-to-make-humanity-less-war-like-should-we/90793#90793

Comment: I suggest your source misinterpreted "between 25% & 75% of soldiers only willing to do this… " for the real truth, which is that between 25% & 75% of soldiers are not capable of doing that; their "willingness" doesn't come into it.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I cited my sources. Motivation is key.

Comment: @CriglCragl Are you seriously offering two members' personal opinions as "sources"?

Either way, can you explain "motivation is key"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Did you not follow the link? The reference was to the book 'Acts of War: Behavior of Men in Battle'. I heard more recently that the issue was, snipering an enemy soldier in the opposite trench would result in vengeance killings, leading to soldiers pleasing officers by shooting, but protecting colleagues by missing. This mindset resulted in the Christmas Truce, & the risk to directors of the war on both sides of the soldiers recognising they had more in common with each other than those leading them..

Comment: @CriglCragl Did you not follow the meaning? Snipering an enemy soldier in the opposite trench might indeed lead to soldiers pleasing officers by shooting, or protecting colleagues by missing.

That mindset might have contributed to the Christmas Truce. Where is the evidence that it did?

If your point is that the directors of war on both sides risk soldiers recognising they have more in common with each other than their leaders, why not say that in the first place?

Anyway, how does that relate to Yossarian's ethics or morals?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Oh I see, it was in reference to the comment. I was citing my own posts on related relevant topics *to the comment*, so no not related to Yossarian. The unwillingness of people in general to murder & die, is a najor theme of Catch 22, & I mention evidence of it to support my conclusion that the book is about: "questioning of whether in truth it can be rational to accept an order to die, and to die for the sake of an order"

Comment: @CriglCragl Oh, right; citing your own posts… To what other philosophies, in what other tomes, might Roger look to compare Yossarian's, d'you think?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: What Yossarian posseses? Or did you mean multiple Yossarians, contrasted? Or books/perspectives to contrast to Yossarian's own? I'd describe a cynic watching 'children ardent for some desperate glory' as brought into special focus by the industrialisation of war, by machineguns & long range artillery. Perhaps 'The Charge of the Light Brigade' describes the moment of change, old lies could no longer cover ordering people to die for no reason, with no threat but death for failure to follow stupid orders. Aping the Song of Roland, & Spartans at Thermopylae, but failing to convince

Comment: @CriglCragl Try 'To what other philosophies might Yossarian's be compared?'

Don't you think the Light Brigade was massacred by mistake, not design? I don't remember Roland but didn't the Spartans make a clear choice, and the Thespians an even more definite decision?

That Roger didn't bother to offer a view for validation is a shame, but so is that fact that SE doesn't want us to do what he Asked: 'explore it deeper'.

Sorry but 'the context of an individual vis-à-vis war' would still be obscure if SE did welcome exploration